# View all nodes by this user: filters or arguments

Tags: php, drupal, content-management-system, drupal-views

I'm generating a view that lists all nodes created by this user. To restrict it to the currently logged in user, do I need to use Filters or Arguments?

I thought `Arguments` -> `User: Uid`, but not sure how to specify current logged user as the argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use "User: Current" as a filter.

If you absolutely want to use an argument, you can select User:Uid as the argument and provide the default argument. Select "User ID from logged in user" as the default.

But sometimes that gets wonky in my experience. The filter seems to work better and should give you what you need.